# How to store the values ​of the size of window, margin and textbox C# WF

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

It is necessary that after closing the program, it retains the size of the window, the values ​​of the CheckBox and what was entered in the TextBox.Can you write me a code?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Add some more information, not clear what's problem your trying to solve

Comment: You cannot expect someone to write you code. :) You should try something yourself and then ask for help/guidance. In your case, you should save data externally on FormClosing event. Save it in database, in registry, in local txt, xml or json file.